Two Monitors Not Working
I'm working with a Lenovo L390 (provided by the new company).
I don't have access to the BIOS.
The monitor only works in Individual mode. If I connect one monitor using HDMI and another monitor using the HDMI-C cable adapter, it doesn't work.
Lenovo L390
GPU: Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2) by Mesa
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS 64-bit
GNOME 42.9 X11
Note: It's not a cable or monitor issue, as they work perfectly fine with my personal computer and previously worked flawlessly with the company's previous notebook.
